# Exception in thread main com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException while converting string to Java object using Jackson library

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to read a string from a text file and want to map it to a bean class but I am getting an unusual exception from jackson library.

I have a made a POJO named Question.java that has all the values that I have to read from the text file.

```
    private String Code;
    private String QuestionCode;
    private String Description;
    private String Type;
    private String LastUpdated;
```

I have main class where I read the string from the text file and try to map it to Question class

```
public class QuestionParser {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Sample.txt"));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append(ls);
        }
        
        stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
        reader.close();
        
        String content = stringBuilder.toString();
        System.out.println(content);
        String sample = content.replaceAll("\\\\", " ");
        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        Question question = mapper.readValue(sample, Question.class);
        System.out.println(question);
        
        
    }

}
```

The Sample.txt looks like

```
{\"Code\":\"60\",
\"QuestionCode\":\"7000\",
\"Description\":\"What is your favorite movie?\",
\"Type\":\"R\",
\"LastUpdated\":\"2015-05-21\"
}
```

After all this when I run the code it gives me below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Code " (class Question), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: "type", "questionCode", "description", "code", "lastUpdated"])

  at [Source: (String)"{ "Code ": "60 ",

  "QuestionCode ": "7000 ",

  "Description ": "What is your favorite movie? ",

  "Type ": "R ",

  "LastUpdated ": "2015-05-21 "

 }

 "; line: 1, column: 13] (through reference chain: Question["Code "])

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:1127)

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1984)

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1701)

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1679)

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:319)

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:176)

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4620)

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3575)

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3543)

    at QuestionParser.main(QuestionParser.java:33)
```

Comment: hi, perhaps make the fields public, so Jackson knows they should be serialized, or add a getter method  like `String getCode()`

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Property names should start with lower character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your replace is creating all the issues. `String sample = content.replaceAll("\\\\", " ");` is adding an additional whitespace to every JSON key. Please use the following code instead:

```java
public class QuestionParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Sample.txt"));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append(ls);
        }
        
        stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
        reader.close();
        
        String content = stringBuilder.toString();
        System.out.println(content);
        String sample = content.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        Question question = mapper.readValue(sample, Question.class);
        System.out.println(question);    
    }
}
```

Mind the changed line: `String sample = content.replaceAll("\\\\", "");`.

Additionally, as @Jens already mentioned, follow Java conventions and follow camelcase for Java property name. Having said this, please also change your `Question` to:

```java
public class Question {
    private String code;
    private String questionCode;
    private String description;
    private String type;
    private String lastUpdated;

    //getters & setters
}
```

Finally, you also need to adjust your JSON as follows:

```json
{\"code\":\"60\",
\"questionCode\":\"7000\",
\"description\":\"What is your favorite movie?\",
\"type\":\"R\",
\"lastUpdated\":\"2015-05-21\"
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Assuming you can't change the JSON file you are trying to read you would need to use `@JsonProperty` annotation in your `Question` class to "glue" the properties together. In this case, JSON would still look as you added in the question:

```json
{\"Code\":\"60\",
\"QuestionCode\":\"7000\",
\"Description\":\"What is your favorite movie?\",
\"Type\":\"R\",
\"LastUpdated\":\"2015-05-21\"
}
```

But your `Question` class would have a bunch of `@JsonProperty` annotations (you can read more about it at https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html):

```java
public class Question {
    @JsonProperty("Code")
    private String code;

    @JsonProperty("QuestionCode")
    private String questionCode;

    @JsonProperty("Description")
    private String description;

    @JsonProperty("Type")
    private String type;

    @JsonProperty("LastUpdated")
    private String lastUpdated;

    //getters & setters
}
```

Comment: You still shouldn't be replacing escape characters. Parsing more than once should properly "solve" that replace problem

Comment: Honestly, I had tried it all but still ended up with the same exception. As for your adjusting JSON point, let me add few more things here....Basically I have to fetch similar kind of data from redis and then parse it into JSON so for now I have kept it a short string that I'm reading from a file but in actual I'll be getting a string with maybe 15 values and it won't be in camelcase format so how do I deal with that?

Comment: That is simply impossible because I tried the solution myself and it worked.

Comment: Assuming you can't change the JSON file you are trying to read you would need to use `@JsonProperty` annotation in your `Question` class to "glue" the properties together. Please check my answer, I've edited it.

Comment: @Codeblocks, is your issue solved now? If it is and my answer helped you consider upvoting it and even accepting it as the answer so that it can be ”closed” and others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!

Comment: @João Dias Yeah I tried upvoting your answer but since I am a new user the site gives me a pop stating I need 15 reputation to cast a vote. I'll definitely vote for the answer once I am eligible for it

Comment: @Codeblocks but if it solved your problem you should consider accepting the answer as the correct one at least ;)

Comment: @João Dias Done!! Thanks once again for helping me out Got to learn something as I am new to JSON parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining and reading the file incorrectly. JSON is not line-delimited, so don't read it as lines

JSON should look like this, for example, no backslashes...

(file extension should ideally be `.json` as well, but doesn't matter except for your text editor)

```
{
  "Code": "60",
  "QuestionCode":"7000"
}
```

Also, the Java field names should be annotated or exactly match the JSON fields; Java fields should be lower-case. You could also remove the quotes in the JSON values if you wanted to use integers or other datatypes than strings

```
public class Question {

 public Question() { }

 @JsonProperty("Code")
 private String code;

 // getters and setters
}
```

Then you can open that using the ObjectMapper directly

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
// File should be in `src/main/resources` folder of a Java project
InputStream is = QuestionParser.class.getResourceAsStream("/questions.json");
Question q = om.readValue(is, Question.class);
```

Comment: If changing the JSON to proper JSON is an option then this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be given that OP has created the file locally and has full access to it

Comment: I am not saying it shouldn't but for whatever reason, that might not be possible (imagine the weird case that this "JSON" is handed over by someone else in this way). But I agree with you, this is by far the best solution if the JSON can be properly created.

Comment: Even so, `om.readValue(om.readValue(is, String.class), Question.class)` would still work to un-escape a correct JSON string

Comment: That is in fact true, thanks for the hint! ;)

Answer (score -2):

After parsing your string contains variable Code like "Code " with whitespace. You should fix replace logic or use annotation.

```
@JsonProperty("Code ")
private String Code;
```

Comment: Property Code should be code, because of java naming conventions. Also remove the blank in the JsonProperty name

Comment: variable name will be Code without whitespace (but will be batter if variable call use camelcase), it is ok for java naming convention. Code with whitespace will be used for mapping json in annotation value. Are you seen my answer? But сertainly fix replacing logic is a best solution but for in needs more time

Comment: use 
@JsonProperty("Code ")
private String code;
as fast solution

Comment: Unrecognized field "Code " you have incorrect parsing logic. And you called variable Code in example above but wrote me about naming convention? Hmm